# unity 5.1.2 Bootstrapper no longer compiling

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, bootstrapper

Prior to the latest Unity 5.1.2 release, I was able to compile the Bootstrapper using UnityBootstrapper.  Now the following piece of code is looking for Microsoft.Practices.Unity 4.0.0 which is no longer available on Nuget. I understand the library is no longer available, but what is the solution?  In the following example Container is no longer found in Unity 5.1.2.  Are Containers no longer used in Unity's DI?

```
protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindowView>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Updated from 4.0.1 to 5.1.2 and ended up nowhere, had to revert to 4.0.1. Would be great to get some info how to upgrade.

Comment: the newest release of PRISM will incorporate the latest update from the UNITY group.